# How do I prevent Bootstrap responsive layout extra space on right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

All of my Bootstrap pages on a site I'm working on have extra space to the right of the content. This extra space causes horizontal scrolling on mobile, tablet and medium screen size. When I have the browser window open VERY wide on my 24" screen the issue does not occur.

I've searched and none of the answers seem to fix my issue.

- I have nothing stating a wider width on any elements that are set at 100% (that I can find).
- I have no padding set on any elements set at 100%
- I have overflow-x : hidden set on html in my theme CSS.

The working site is at        http://www.bizharbour.net/projects/jambalaya

This happens even on the home page, which does not have any extra js plugins, such as the lightbox that appears on other pages.

I have no idea what's causing the issue.

Comment: seems alright on my end?

Comment: Thanks HenryW. That has just given me an inspiration. It appears it's a browser thing. It's happening in Safari 6.0.2 on the Mac and in Chrome on an Android Tablet and an Android mobile. It's fine in Firefox on the Mac and Windows 7, and in IE 11 on Windows 7. So Chrome and Safari are getting the horizontal scrolling. Any ideas?

Comment: i think your problem is within the #id `main-wrap` put that div inside a div called `<div class="container"><div id="main-wrap">...</div></div>`

Comment: FYI , just checked with CHROME , and there it also is good... no issues @all (homepage) + checked on android (HTC ONE mobile)..also perfect.

Comment: Hi HenryW, Thanks for the tip. I will give it a try. The CSS fix from Scooterlord appears to have fixed it on Chrome in Android, but not in Safari (See my comment below). Thanks for checking it in Chrome and on your mobile. One of those particular browser/platform issues it seems.

Comment: Just in case you're wondering, I went for the CSS fix because it was the quickest one to implement if it worked :)

Comment: Hi HenryW, I tried your fix but unfortunately it created extra padding. See a screenshot at http://www.bizharbour.net/projects/jambalaya/jambalaya.jpg. I could delete the padding:20px from #mainwrap but it didn't solve my original problem. So unless it's necessary to have that .container for any other reason, I'm going to scrap it. Would be interested to hear whether it is necessary. Would rather avoid issues at a later date if I can. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...what is causing the issue is the 'carousel-indicators' class.

the following code will fix your problem if you overwrite your current code, or alter it accordingly.

```
.carousel-indicators {
  left:auto;
  right:20px;
  margin-right:0;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi Scooterlord, Thanks for the code. I've made that change so my css is now: '.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
   z-index: 15;
  left:auto;
  right:20px;
  margin-right:0;
  width:auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  bottom: 10px;
}'

Comment: Hit return by mistake. To continue --> It has fixed it on the Android mobile but not in Safari on my Mac (that could be some kind of cache issue). So I will check again later and post back.

Comment: I am certain that THIS is the error. When you confirm it let me know.

Comment: It's still moving all over the place on Chrome Android on the Galaxy Tab 4 (10.1")and Safari on the Mac. Rock solid on Chrome Android on the Moto E. Something to do with the media queries for the larger displays maybe? Although having checked, there are no references to .carousel-indicators on those media queries. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I've just found .carousel-indicators under '@media (min-width: 768px) {...'. Have made your amendments and it's now fixed on Chrome and Safari. Thanks for your persistence. Cheers, Tracy

Comment: Glad I could help. You'll have to find a way to make up for it! :D